# Way to get and edit GET variables in order to make hyperlinks

Tags: php, hyperlink, get, global-variables

Let's say that I have URL like `somefile.php?sort=id&way=desc`.

I want to write a function (or use already made one) that would let me add next variables to URL and set which I want to delete.

I thought about something like `function editGetVar("$add","$leave")` where `$add` would be array with new variables to add to URL and `$leave` would be array with variables that must stay in URL.

Example:

```
somefile.php?sort=id&way=desc&buyer=retailer
```

and I want to delete "buyer" and add "action", then the `a href` would look like this:

```
<a href="somefile.php?sort=id&way=desc&action=edit">
```

I would appreciate any ideas from you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [http_build_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php):

```
<?php
unset($_GET['buyer']);
$_GET['action'] = 'edit';

print '<a href="somefile.php?' . http_build_query($_GET) . '">!!</a>';
?>
```

Comment: although it would be wise to not modify the $_GET variable, make a copy first

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can split up the URI with `$parts = parse_url($my_uri)`, manipulate the resulting array and stick it back together with the `http_build_query` function.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
$url = '?';
foreach( $_POST as $key => $value )
{
    $url .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
}
```

You can add/edit a variable as:

```
$_GET[ 'sort' ] = 'asc';
```

You can delete as:

```
unlink( $_GET[ 'sort' ] );
```

You can wrap it into a function yourself ;)

Comment: yeah that would be ruthless to type